# Animating model instances

Tags: animation, instances

I model a digger assembled of multiple parts, place several instances of it into the scene and animate each instance's bucket individually within the rotation constraints specified by the model.

This is the task to be performed. An everday's task and a core requirement for an animation software.

Or, construct a car and put some of this same brand and model into the scene. One should steer to the left, another one to the right, the next one's window is open and another one's trunk is open. They are all instances of the same model, just with movable parts to be animated within the limits as specified with the model.

My problem is that it's not doable in an acceptable way:

- Copying the objects the digger is made of would mean that any future change to the model would have to be done numerous times with every instance. Copies are not instances.
- The parts of group instances are frozen. The group's objects, like the bucket, are not rotatable individually.

After 15 years of trying to work with Blender, stumbling across this again and again, I'd really like to know this now.

Thanks

Comment: Hooks work for instanced meshes or objects, you can press `Ctrl`+`H` *> Hook to new object*. If I understand you correctly, this should work. Let me know if it does or does not.

Comment: Novice,  
I'm sorry, I do not understand the relation to the question. I know the hook modifier. Ctrl+H sets the "restrict render" option. To which part of the digger should the hook be attached? The wheels? The bucket?
First I need to know how to place several instances of my digger into the scene.

Comment: Whatever you want to animate. In Edit mode, select a set of vertices, and do it. To create an instance of an object, use `Alt`+`D`.

Comment: I do not want to animate vertices, consequently I do not need to go into edit mode. All vertices will stay at their positions. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What are you animating? Bones? You can do it for them too

Comment: I think the question was pretty clear. The model is made of several objects. One of them is the bucket. Others can be the wheels or whatever other parts the digger is made of. Objects can be animated by moving and rotating them. Taking the digger example, the bucket can be raised or lowered, maybe by rotating an arm it is attached to (parented).

Comment: You mean how to make a keyframe? Use `I` and select rotation, location, scale, or any combination

Comment: I know how to make keyframes. My question is: how can I create a model consisting of several objects and place multiple instances of this model into the scene, then animate each instance separately (e.g. by rotating parts of the model as described before). Copying the model is not an option as every future change of the model would have to be done multiple times. Group instances are not an option, too, as the objects of group instances are not animatable individually. (Sorry, unable to move this to a chat due to "insufficient reputation")

Comment: Yeah, I'm not quite understanding the issue I don't think. Using `Alt`+`D`, you can make an instance, and it is fully animatable completely separately. I won't be available much this morning (if any), but when I get back I can open a chat room and we can post images to show what we mean :/

Comment: If not, I've uploaded a blend file here: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9264561bd157a867!214&authkey=!AAYkuhxvlLbvdJ4&ithint=file%2cblend  I've added two group instances. Of course, the buckets can not be raised/lowered individually. You can pres Ctrl+Right to switch to the other scene containing the group objects. Doing w/o groups, we could copy (alt+d) all parts of the digger. Copies are bad, e.g. if you decide to lower the distance of the pillars you'd have to do it with every copy. thanks.

Comment: How did you make those objects?! Did you link them from another file? I can't see how you got the mesh and the empty to be included in one object.

Comment: We can extend this discussion in this chat room: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24779/animating-model-instances-question-discussion

Comment: I'm sorry, chatting doesn't work. It tells me to login but I am already. I've already checked browser settings (java script, cookies). Anyway, as I said, these are group instances. You can't edit group instances. As I also said, switch to the next screen layout (Ctrl+Right) to see the group objects.

Comment: Did you try refreshing the page? Also you may not have enough rep. This is the test file I made: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36542

Comment: I'v downloaded it meanwhile. Thx. You've joined the objects into one. My situation is different as my digger is made of **multiple objects**. I do not want to join anything as wheels and other parts are separate meshes.

Comment: If they are seperate, simply parent them to empties (select mesh, then the empty, and press `Ctrl`+`P`). The same principle applies

Comment: Yeah, the bucket is already parented to an empty which is used to rotate the pillars and the bucket. I didn't find out how hooks can help here because my question would still have been how to create a digger model made of several parts, place multiple instances of the model into the scene, being able to animate parts of the model seperately, and every change of the model is reflected within all instances, but as I'm starting at the beginning again, I consider this closed for my part. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You need to use `Alt`+`D`, that will make all changes to one object be copied to all other instances. You should be able to animate such objects separately without any special parts. This is kind of common knowledge so I assumed you knew that. Just out of curiosity, what blender version are you using? THat could make a huge difference. I am using 2.74

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to add an armature and rig it to your mesh.  The various armatures can be posed and animated independently although they share a single armature datablock.  The same with the objects instantiating the mesh.

I found a couple of rigging tutorials by searching for  blender armature rigging.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9iL1hmJXrI
- http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-to-rigging/

And the Humane Rigging series is somewhat legendary

- https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE211C8C41F1AFBAB

It is entirely possible to place multiple independent meshes under control of a single armature by giving each mesh an armature modifier pointing at the controlling armature.  This still requires assignment of vertex groups, but you would have to do that in a single-mesh situation anyway.

An even simpler system is to give each mesh a "child of" constraint and make it the child of a single bone in the armature.  This is only appropriate if each mesh is a single rigid element, but if your objects are constructed in this way, you do not have to assign vertex groups.

I am not sure what problem you are solving with proxies.  When I am linking assets from external files, I often end clicking Make Local on the Object datablock (storing positions, constraints, modifiers, etc) and the Mesh datablock is still a link to the source .blend.  Changes to the mesh will be reflected in the linking .blend upon next load.  The drawback is that changes to the modifiers and object position would not be.

My suspicion is that blender can accomplish the vast majority of what you want to do, but some of the workflow steps are not covered by the tutorials you have read yet.

Comment: I know how to rig one mesh. A digger is not one single mesh because it's an assembly of **several separate parts**. If you joined all parts to one big mesh, you would create copies and redundant vertex definitions. Copying is bad because every change of a certain part has to be done multiple times, so don't do this. But this is basic modeling knowledge. If we disagree here, it's pointless for me to continue regarding this subject. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'll add some more to my answer to explain.

Comment: Some final words in a plain-text file uploaded to avoid a lengthy discussion here:   
http://1drv.ms/1QwUkKx

Comment: Ok, I fail to understand. Maybe a solution based on my simple digger example makes sense. It should show  

- a digger model assembled by several objects
- some instances of the digger model
- raising/lowering the bucket of every instance individually (there is already a rotatable empty for this purpose)
- changes to the model must be reflected within all instances of the model. For example, changing the distance between the pillars of the digger model must automatically be reflected with all instances. No copying, scripts, drivers should be required.  

continued...

Comment: I do not necessarily need group instances, armatures, etc. for this, just the most simple approach. Sorry, my formatting is gone in the previous comment. Edit: I see it's not possible in a comment.